# Magento upgrade from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 problems

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5p1, php8

I upgraded my magento store from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 and changed php version from 7.4 to 8.1 and I ran "composer update" successfully, then upgrade,compile and deploy static content.
Now i have a problem with the topsearch it doesnt show me search recommendations and that is the error in (system.log)
"/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php(329): Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->_insertChild('header-wrapper', 'top.search.byca...', NULL, 'topSearch')"

And when i tried to install cron jobs I got this error in (magento.cron.log)
"Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 7.4.33. in /public_html/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24"
although when I checked the php version in cpanel MultiPHP Manager it was 8.1 also I ran php -v in terminal and it showed 8.1

Comment: If your php -v and phpinfo gaving same php version then command start from php bin/Magento
If both version are different then you have to run with php path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened when you have disabled PHP functions: exec. ask your hosting provider or modify your php.ini file to remove it form disable_functions. then try to run php bin/magento cron:install --force

Answer (score 1):

If you run apache as www-data check your crontab by running in terminal
sudo crontab -u www-data -e to check if you are "really" using /usr/bin/php (php8.1 as you said) or the /usr/bin/php7.4